# SQL - delete all except the last N rows by serial_numb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table with a lot of records every second in each serial number. I want to get only the last 10 records of each serial number to be saved.

This is the structure of the database:[image]

I am trying this code but I get an error: `This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

```
DELETE
    FROM instant_data m1
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT m2.id
                     FROM instant_data m2
                     WHERE m2.serial_numb = m1.serial_numb
                     ORDER BY m2.id DESC
                     LIMIT 30);
```

Comment: What is precise MariaDB version?

Comment: 5.5.61-MariaDB-38.13

Answer (score 1):

```sql
DELETE instant_data 
FROM instant_data 
JOIN ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serial_numb ORDER BY id DESC) rn 
       FROM instant_data  ) cte USING (id)
WHERE cte.rn > 10;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=3a76cd142d538c7da687f595e0180729

Comment: Brilliant! It works, but is there a way to do it with a single query?

Comment: I get `Something is wrong in your syntax near '(PARTITION BY serial_numb ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
       FROM instant_data) cte 'on line 3`

Comment: @OscarFuentes This is not MySQL/MariaDB error message, so it is produced by used client. Obtain original message received from DB server.

Comment: How can I obtain original message?

Comment: @OscarFuentes Execute this query using command-line client (CLI, mysql.exe). or look your client for detailed protocol.